# Precinct Name Change Across Time

Tags: usa, us-census, elections

I am looking for one or several sources that record changes in precinct names across time in the US (at least after the 2000s).

I have looked on individual states' webpages, as well as other website such as [this](http://www.usboundary.com/). I can only find current names/codes of precincts but not the corresponding codes of those precincts that may have split or joined others across time.

For example, no county has the same number of precincts and precinct names in 2000 as it does in 2018. I am interested in knowing, say, whether a precinct called 1-1 in 2000 is the same as one called 1-1A in 2018 in a given county. Any leads would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best source that I know of for precinct shapefiles is https://github.com/nvkelso/election-geodata.

From this data, you would be able to identify whether a precinct has the same geography between elections and the same name, or whether either the geography or name has changed.